# Subfigure Caption Problem

Tags: floats

I am trying to have subfigures within one figure lets say Figure 1 , below is the code I have now. The problem is it doesn't show after I compile the tex and under the figures the following caption Fig1a:fishfigure and Fig1a:catfigure it shows instead: the following (a)fishfigure (b)catfigure...

Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfigure[fish figure]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{fish}%
\label{fig:fish}%
}
\hfil
\subfigure
[cat figure]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{cat}%
\label{fig:cat}%
}
\hfil
\subfigure
[dogfigure]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{dog}%
\label{fig:dog}%
       }
     \end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi, right now, i don't even understand the question. Can you [provide a test case](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/)? This would say more than a thousand words.

Comment: btw, right now, package `subcaption` is recommended to do the job.

Comment: @Johannes_B
The code I provided should put three figures as subfigures, the caption of the figures do not show Fig1(a) Fig1(b) Fig1(c), it shows instead (a) (b) (c)...

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package instead of the obsolete `subfigure`, redefine `\thesubfigure` and declare the desired format for the label using `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat`:

A little example, using `\subcaptionbox` (another options would be to use the `subfigure` *environment* from `subcaption`):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subcaption}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure(\alph{subfigure})}
\renewcommand\p@subfigure{}
\makeatother
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{prefixsubfig}{Fig#1#2:}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=prefixsubfig}

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{fish figure\label{fig:fish}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{fish}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{cat figure\label{fig:cat}}{%
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{cat}}\par
\subcaptionbox{dogfigure\label{fig:dog}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{dog}}
\end{figure}

As we see in subfigures~\ref{fig:fish}, \ref{fig:cat}, and~\ref{fig:dog}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: How many years will pass before `subfigure` goes into oblivion? :)